# Failed to execute goal org.apache.portals.jetspeed-2:jetspeed-mvn-maven-plugin:2.3.0:mvn

Tags: java, jetspeed2

i have problem when build jetspeed project in cmd: mvn jetspeed:mvn -Dtarget=all
and it show:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.portals.jetspeed-2:jetspeed-mvn-maven-plugin:2.3.0:mvn (default-cli) on project jetexpress: ...FAILED[error invoking Maven] -> [Help 1]
help me!!!
tks to all

Comment: I'm not sure what the state of the jetspeed-2 maven plugin is these days, but as a work around, are you able to deploy your application manually? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Hi John, i;m trying tutorial jetspeed-2 with maven. it here http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/tutorial/index.html i real quite deadlock.